# Installing and using wxWidgets with Cygwin on Windows

Tags: cygwin, wxwidgets

I have wxWidgets on windows and have it working with VS 2017.  I now want to try with Cygwin.  Following the steps in the install.txt, which can be found here, https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/docs/msw/install.txt, gave the following errors:

$ make

/cygdrive/c/wxWidgets-3.1.0/bk-deps g++ -c -o basedll_string.o  -D__WXMSW__      -DWXBUILDING -I/cygdrive/c/wxWidgets-3.1.0/src/tiff/libtiff -I./src/tiff/libtiff -I./src/jpeg -I./src/png -I./src/zlib -I./src/regex -I./src/expat/lib -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -DWXMAKINGDLL_BASE -DwxUSE_BASE=1  -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/cygdrive/c/wxWidgets-3.1.0/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-3.1 -I./include -O2  ./src/common/string.cpp
In file included from ./src/common/string.cpp:39:0:

./include/wx/xlocale.h: In function ‘double wxStrtod_lA(const char*, char**, const wxXLocale&)’:

./include/wx/xlocale.h:243:54: error: ‘strtod_l’ was not declared in this scope
         { return wxCRT_Strtod_lA(c, endptr, loc.Get()); }
                                                      ^

./include/wx/xlocale.h: In function ‘long int wxStrtol_lA(const char*, char**, int, const wxXLocale&)’:

./include/wx/xlocale.h:245:60: error: ‘strtol_l’ was not declared in this scope
         { return wxCRT_Strtol_lA(c, endptr, base, loc.Get()); }
                                                            ^

./include/wx/xlocale.h: In function ‘long unsigned int wxStrtoul_lA(const char*, char**, int, const wxXLocale&)’:

./include/wx/xlocale.h:247:61: error: ‘strtoul_l’ was not declared in this scope
         { return wxCRT_Strtoul_lA(c, endptr, base, loc.Get()); }
                                                             ^

./include/wx/xlocale.h: In function ‘double wxStrtod_l(const wchar_t*, wchar_t**, const wxXLocale&)’:

./include/wx/xlocale.h:301:58: error: ‘wcstod_l’ was not declared in this scope
             { return wxCRT_Strtod_lW(c, endptr, loc.Get()); }
                                                          ^

./include/wx/xlocale.h: In function ‘long int wxStrtol_l(const wchar_t*, wchar_t**, int, const wxXLocale&)’:

./include/wx/xlocale.h:303:64: error: ‘wcstol_l’ was not declared in this scope
             { return wxCRT_Strtol_lW(c, endptr, base, loc.Get()); }
                                                                ^

./include/wx/xlocale.h: In function ‘long unsigned int wxStrtoul_l(const wchar_t*, wchar_t**, int, const wxXLocale&)’:

./include/wx/xlocale.h:305:65: error: ‘wcstoul_l’ was not declared in this scope
             { return wxCRT_Strtoul_lW(c, endptr, base, loc.Get()); }
                                                                 ^
make: *** [Makefile:25366: basedll_string.o] Error 1

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What version of g++ do you use? What version of Cygwin? Can you try with the Git HEAD? Did you use any configure options?

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin already has the wxWidgets libraries

Full list on
https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look this up.  I had installed cygwin and gcc/c++ solely for OpenMP, etc.  Since I already had a wxWidgets download I just thought it would be easy enough to rebuild for cygwin rather than install new.  I did not install all packages with cygwin.  Will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `--disable-xlocale` configure option to work around this particular problem, but the current Git master is tested with [Appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/wxWidgets/wxwidgets) under Cygwin and build fine there, so it might be worth updating your sources to the latest version.

Generally speaking, please notice that Cygwin is not a Tier-1 platform for wxWidgets, so I wouldn't recommend using it unless you have some really good reasons for it. wxWidgets is all about using native APIs and it's difficult to marry it with the Cygwin approach of providing Unix APIs under MSW, so it's not a particularly happy combination, unfortunately (I'm saying this as a long time Cygwin user who likes it a lot -- but I still don't use it for developing under MSW).

Comment: Yes, I read about that issue and had planned to switch to mingw, or build in Cygwin with a different set of libs (something that is possible).  Why the gymnastics?  I already have wxWidgets working with VS 2017, and PLplot, but cannot seem to get the two to work together.  I thought of trying to rebuild everything with different compiler as I've seen a lot of unresolved issues with this configuration, and have not been able to get a resolution to the wxWidgets+Plplot+VS issues appealing to several resources.